# How can I view customer order on frontend with own form?

Tags: sales-order

Guest and registered customers can see their order if they go to `sales/guest/form/` on the frontend and fill in their order and email details into the form. On submit they get directed through to `sales/guest/view/`

I want to be able to go to the `sales/guest/view` from a route of my own, e.g. an option on the contact us page where I get the customer's email and order number.

From there I have tried loading the order and saving it in registry, to seeing if this works: `$this->_redirect('sales/guest/view', array('order_id', $order->getId()));`

but if I try that it just redirects me to the form.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by storing the order in the registry as 'current-order' and then setting some defaults in 'guest-cookie', then doing a redirect from my controller to the correct form:

```
    Mage::register('current_order', $order);
    $cookieModel = Mage::getSingleton('core/cookie');
    $toCookie = base64_encode($order->getProtectCode() . ':' . $order->getIncrementId());
    $cookieModel->set('guest-view', $toCookie, 3600, '/');
    session_write_close(); //THIS LINE IS VERY IMPORTANT!
    $this->_redirect('sales/guest/view');
```

The session_write_close is there for my 'addSuccess' message that goes at the top of the page.